# How do I avoid overlapping buttons on a LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I know how to create a custom dialog with an predefined XML.

I would like to create a dialog with a LinearLayout and buttons dynamically.

I tried the code below, but its seems my buttons are overlapping. How do I prevent this?

```
public void createMenu(MenuItem item){

    Dialog menuDiag = new Dialog(Home.this);
    menuDiag.setTitle("Browse");    
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(menuDiag.getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams  params;


    Button button;

    categoryList = parse.getPlayList(); 

    for(int i=0;i<categoryList.size();i++){     
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        button =  new Button(menuDiag.getContext());
        button.setText(categoryList.get(i).getTitle());
        button.setBackgroundResource(iconCheck(categoryList.get(i).getTitle()));
        button.setLayoutParams(params);

        menuDiag.addContentView(button, params);


    }

    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    menuDiag.addContentView(linearLayout, params);
    menuDiag.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting orientation of your `LinearLayout` to Vertical, this way it will automatically be placed below the first `View`

If you are using `LinearLayout` then use

`yourLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`

to set the orientation